# Refresh PostgreSQL table to show new fields

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have PostgreSQL/PostGIS tables and am adding fields in DB Manager. I have to remove and add the tables to QGIS for the new fields to appear.

I have tried:

- Reload table (the icon in the attribute table)
- Refresh (F5)

But the fields don't show up. Isn't there some way besides removing and re-adding the layers? This is a bit annoying when I have set a symbology in QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save the QGIS project, close QGIS and re-open the project.

The new column will be readily available.

Alternatively, add the layer a 2nd time, then copy-paste the style before removing the 1st (old) one.

Comment: Just a detail: no need to close QGis, simply re-open the project.